# NetBeans | How to change font size in JavaDoc window?

Tags: netbeans, documentation

How to change font size in Window -> IDE Tools windows?
I tried, but I can't. Help me please, anyone knows !

Answer (score 1):

In **Netbeans 8.0.2**:

- Right Click an IDE Tools Window
- Select Larger Font

**[Note]** *Ctrl+Up* will also increase the font size with certain IDE Tools Windows have the focus.